# How to trigger the value in combobox with gecko?

Tags: c#, combobox, onchange, geckofx

```html
<select id="gamemode" class="form-control" onchange="setserver2($(this).val());" required=""><option id="ffa1" value="14.24.125.101:1002">FFA-1</option><option id="ffa2" value="255.242.165.54:1002">FFA-2</option><option id="ffa3" value="255.242.165.54:1003">FFA-3</option><option id="ffa4" value="255.242.165.54:1004">FFA-4</option><option id="ffa5" value="255.242.165.54:1005">FFA-5</option><option id="ffa6" value="255.242.165.54:1006">FFA-6</option><option id="ffa7" value="255.242.165.54:1007">FFA-7</option><option id="ffa8" value="38.136.25.115:1001">FFA-8</option><option id="ffa9" value="38.136.25.115:1002">FFA-9</option><option id="ffa10" value="38.136.25.115:1003">FFA-10</option><option id="ffa11" value="38.136.25.115:1004">FFA-11</option><option id="ffa12"
```

With this code I show the value in the ComboBox but it is not active.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "FFA-1")
        {
            var mode = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoSelectElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetHtmlElementById("gamemode").DOMHtmlElement);
            mode.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

How to trigger the value in ComboBox with gecko

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of the checkbox from your code, or the other way round - react to when the value of the combobox is changed by a user?

Comment: i am trying to set the value of the combobox from my code. When combobox selected to any value, page's combobox must change. With this code, page's combobox is changing but only changing it's name. İt's value not active. I solved my problem with this method: geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:setserver2('14.24.125.101:1002')");

Comment: You should trigger the 'onchange' event after selecting the index

Comment: I already asked how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
nsAStringBase eventType = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString("change");
var ev = wb.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents");
ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, false, false);
mode.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
```